# org.hibernate.MappingException migrating to JBoss 7

Tags: jpa, jboss, jboss7.x, jpa-2.0

I am migrating two apps from JBoss 5.1 EAP to JBoss AS 7.1.1. The applications have their own databases, but contain many tables that have a common layout. The annotated entity classes for these common tables are defined in common.jar, which resides in the {jboss.server.home.url}/lib directory, and the entity classes are defined in the application EAR's persistence.xml. Other app-specific entity classes are packaged inside an EJB JAR inside the EAR.

Since the {jboss.server.home.url}/lib directory directory no longer exists in JBoss7, I want to package common.jar inside the EAR's lib directory, so that the EAR now looks like this:

app.ear

```
/META-INF/
    persistence.xml
    MANIFEST.MF
    application.xml
/lib/
    common.jar
app-ejb.jar
app.war
```

The persistence unit in persistence.xml is defined as

```
<persistence-unit name="ca" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/appDS</jta-data-source>
    <class>com.mycorp.entity.CommonTable1</class>
    <class>com.mycorp.entity.CommonTable2</class>
    <class>com.mycorp.app.entity.AppSpecificTable</class>
    <jar-file>common.jar</jar-file>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
        <property name="jboss.entity.manager.factory.jndi.name" value="java:jboss/appEntityManagerFactory"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

However, when I deploy the app JPA doesn't find my annotated entity classes in common.jar:

```
18:17:02,903 TRACE [org.jboss.as.jpa] getClassesInJar url=/content/common.jar annotations=[interface javax.persistence.MappedSuperclass, interface javax.persistence.Entity, interface javax.persistence.Embeddable]
18:17:02,909 TRACE [org.jboss.as.jpa] No classes to scan for annotations in jar 'vfs:/content/common.jar' (jars with classes '[vfs:/content/app.ear/lib/common.jar/, vfs:/content/app.ear/app-ejb.jar/]')
18:17:02,910 TRACE [org.jboss.as.jpa] getPackagesInJar url=/content/common.jar annotations=[]
18:17:02,910 TRACE [org.jboss.as.jpa] No classes to scan for annotations in jar 'vfs:/content/common.jar' (jars with classes '[vfs:/content/app.ear/lib/common.jar/, vfs:/content/app.ear/app-ejb.jar/]')
```

And this later results in this a "org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: com.mycorp.entity.CommonTable1" exception.

I'm assuming this is some sort of classloader problem, but I'm at a loss to figure out how to allow JPA to see my entity classes.